# Limit of these two functions?

Tags: calculus, limits

limit of $((-1)^x)/x$ as $x$ -> $\infty$

and

limit of  $\sec(1/x)$ as $x$ -> $\infty$

I can eyeball them and see that the answers are $0$ and $1$ but how do I show it more formally?

Comment: The first one indeed is zero (bounded function/sequence times one that tends to zero), but the other limit is *not* zero.

Comment: @DonAntonio I said first one was $0$, second one is $1$

Comment: What is $(-1)^{\pi}$? You need to make clear that it's a sequence. This is done by using $n$ instead of $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint to first limit, extending Laplacian Fourier's answer:

- As $x \to \infty$, if $x$ is even, $\frac{(-1)^x}{x} = \frac1x$, and,
- if $x$ is odd, $\frac{(-1)^x}{x} = -\frac1x$, so
  $$-\frac1x \leq \frac{(-1)^x}{x} \leq \frac{1}{x}$$
  You also know that $$\lim\frac{\pm1}x = 0,$$ so, by the Squeeze theorem, $$\lim \frac{(-1)^x}x = 0$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For the first one, squeeze it between $-1/x$ and $1/x$
For the second, you can bring the limit inside the secant as it is continious for $x>1$.

Comment: How do you know how to squeeze it like that / how do you know it is valid? Limit of both -1/x and 1/x are obviously $0$ but how do you know the limit is actually between those two?

Comment: [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) is the answer.

Comment: I know about the theorem, I am asking how it is applied here